# Xcode won't recognize/read file properly

Tags: c++, xcode, fstream

I built a program in c++ to calculate the amount of gas money I owe to my dad for my summer job at Domino's. What the program does is read two lines from a file in a do while loop, one for the starting mileage that day and one for the ending mileage of that day. However I just can't get the program to read the file properly. I'm positive I opened it correctly and put it in the right spot (same folder as the .cpp file) but it just won't read it properly. Any ideas?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
ifstream inputFile;

inputFile.open("sample.txt");

int days; // number of days Alisha worked
int count = 1;
int totalMileage = 0;
int addMileage;
int startMileage;
int endMileage;
double avgMileage;
double moneyOwed;
double realOwed;
const double PER_MILE = 0.08125;

cout << endl;

cout << "How many days did Alisha work?" << endl;
cin >> days;

days++;

do
{
    inputFile >> startMileage;
    cout << "The starting mileage for day " << count << " is " << startMileage << endl;

    inputFile >> endMileage;
    cout << "The ending mileage for day " << count << " is " << endMileage << endl;

    addMileage = endMileage - startMileage;

    totalMileage = totalMileage + addMileage;

    count++;

    cout << endl;
}
while (count != days);
```

Comment: Is it correct to assume that there is nothing else in the file but the mileage? Perhaps there is an endline issue. In this case, you can solve things with [std::istream::ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/).

Comment: "I'm positive I opened it correctly" - without a test for `inputFile` validity, how exactly are you positive of that? And Xcode has an integrated debugger anyway, so it will probably be helpful in rooting your problem out. Fwiw, the current working directory for Xcode execution of a cpp-project is normally *not* the same folder as your .cpp file. It's the build-folder where the executable was written. You can change the working directory at startup by editing the Scheme if desired.